# Having with sub-query vs just joining onto table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, having

Working on some SQL today I came across a query that is using `HAVING` with a sub-query. I found it a bit odd as the table in the sub-query only contains one column of values and I figured it would just be simpler to join on that table.

Note the `[F Types]` table is a single column of unique values.

Example of what I found:

```
SELECT ST.COL1, ST.COL2, ST.COL3
FROM SOME_TABLE ST
HAVING ST.TYPE In (Select [Type] from [F Types]);
```

I was thinking that this would do the same thing and probably be better:

```
SELECT ST.COL1, ST.COL2, ST.COL3
FROM SOME_TABLE ST
JOIN [F Types] FT
    ON ST.TYPE = FT.Types
```

I just wanted to make sure I was not missing something as I don't see why one would use `HAVING` here.

What if any is the differenct between the 2 examples?

Comment: The join version may return duplicates, if there are duplicates in Ftypes.

Comment: BTW, use WHERE instead of HAVING here, since the HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: @jarlh I typically use WHERE. I still have not had a use for HAVING in any of my personal queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `WHERE`, not `HAVING`.  `HAVING` is for aggregation queries.  So your question is about:

```
SELECT ST.COL1, ST.COL2, ST.COL3
FROM SOME_TABLE ST
WHERE ST.TYPE In (SELECT f.[Type] FROM [F Types] f);
```

This is often preferable to the `JOIN` query.  You do not have to worry about duplicates in `[F Types]` resulting in duplicate rows in the result set.

```
SELECT ST.COL1, ST.COL2, ST.COL3
FROM SOME_TABLE ST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [F Types] f WHERE f.[Type] = ST.TYPE);
```

This readily takes advantage of an index on `[F Types]([Type])` and is often the fastest approach (although all three should be comparable).

All this said, nothing is wrong with the `JOIN`.  Just under some circumstances it can produce unwanted duplicates.

Often, this is written using `EXISTS` rather than `IN`:

Comment: So in this case JOIN is fine because I know that the table with the 1 column is all unique data but would be better to use `WHERE EXISTS` as good practice just in case.

Comment: @Mike-SMT . . . All three are fine.  I lean toward `EXISTS` because you are only selecting columns from one table and I know it cannot result in duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

either way works, I think joins are technically faster

Comment: Sorry I have updated my post with a clearer example. I just used * as there were like 30 select statements.

Comment: what type of join are you using, it could still result in duplicate rows of data if the ft.type field isn't a distinct id on that table.

Comment: The table column is unique. and its just a JOIN (aka INNER JOIN). But for the sake of argument say the table column was not unique. In that case the HAVING statement could produce duplicate results but I don't think the JOIN would or is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: either way works, I think joins are technically faster, but having is easier to read.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for clarifying. If you could update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Looks like there is some more details to consider according to the other posters. Joins could cost more it would seam.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, a join is used when you actually want additional columns data which are present in the other table to be joined

While, a subquery is used as a lookup reference on some table to refer the data meaning just for reference

Adding to the above difference Join could be still costly imagine with a huge set of records which takes a lot while referring only via subquery would be more costly on performing a join.

Comment: Good to know. The table being joined on only has 1 column so the HAVING and JOIN probably wont have much of a performance difference in this case but I will keep that in mind for down the road.